# LearnDash how to create Quiz Question Category in Parent/Child Hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, learndash

I am working on the LearnDash plugin in which I have a requirement to create a Quiz Question category in Parent/Child Hierarchy.

From Quiz Question, I am able to create Category only , how Do I arrange it in Parent/Child Hierarchy ?

[image]

PS : I don't want to create a custom taxonomy , I want to make it work with the default LearnDash Quiz Question category.